# Button disabling is not working on JavaScript section

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

On a RoR website home page I need to disable a button while a text blank is empty.

Here is the HAML code of the button :

https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/22/2/1559049919-btn.jpg

Here is my JavaScript code supposed to conditions the disabling :

https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/22/2/1559050733-disabled.jpg

Adding "disabled = true" in my HAML works but not in the JS (so the button stays disabled during all process which is -obviously- not what we want)

I already tried to use the disable command line out of if/else and it is still not working.

I'm a newbie in RoR so it is probably a grammatical mistake

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Use `prop()` instead: `$(".save_task_button").prop("disabled", true")`

Comment: It works ! Thank you for yout fast help mate

Comment: No problem. I would recommend pasting your code next time rather than linking it. It can attract downvotes if you do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$('.save_task_btn').attr("disabled", true);
$('.save_task_btn').attr("disabled", false);
```

instead of

```
$('.save_task_btn').disabled = true;
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. It didn't work but 'prop' made the tricks :)